# Как вставить фон в код PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pygame

Вот мой код

```
import pygame

import time

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load("muzyka-dlya-yutuba--5-by-nightland.mp3")

pygame.mixer.music.play()

time.sleep(0) 

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


from_class = uic.loadUiType("obigre.ui")[0]

class my_fon(QtGui.QMainWindow, from_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
                 QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
                 self.setupUi(self)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = my_fon()
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Мне надо поставить фон

Comment: И `php` тут каким боком, подскажите?

Comment: Уважаемый вы ошиблись разделом не php, а python

Comment: А что значит вставить фон? Хотите показать виджет так, чтобы музыка одновременно играла (не думаю, что pygame в отдельном потоке ее воспроизводит, а значит пока мелодия не проиграет, код дальше выполняться не будет и окно не появится)?